# How to get "drwx---r-x+" folder permission using CHMOD? - Bash script

Tags: macos, bash, unix, chmod

I am facing a problem when moving some files across my network and seems to be caused by file permissions.

Currently I have folders with this permissions drwxrwxrwx. 
I need to run a bash script that change permissions to drwx---r-x+

ACL needs to be there.

I don't quite understand how can I achieve the same permissions using CHMOD commands. I have tried so far:

chmod -R ugo=rx "file"

But this seems to change to dr-xr-xr-x, which is not enough...

So the question is, which command should I run to achieve drwx---r-x+ ??

Thanks in advance.

PS. This command must run in MACOSX Maveriks so "setfacl" command will not help.

Comment: Not very familiar with Mac, but afaik, you can set acls with chmod +/-/=a. followed by list of permissions. Perhaps there is info about it in chmod man/help page. I believe you can list special permissions with ls -le

Comment: `info` page for `ls` indicates, regarding the + character: *"Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies whether an alternate access method such as an access control list applies to the file... A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is marked with a '+' character"*

Comment: Try these relevant links: https://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2011/06/04/acls-on-mac-os-x, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30774, http://serverfault.com/questions/182213

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The permissions `drwx---r-x+` break down as follows:

- `d` is a directory, of course.
- `rwx` means it's readable, writeable and accessible by the **u**ser.  These three bits can be represented by the octal number `7`.
- `---` means that the three aforementioned bits are NOT set for the **g**roup assigned to the directory.  No bits are set, so the octal number is `0`.
- `r-x` means that users who aren't matched by the first two categories -- that is, everybody else, or "**o**ther" -- can read and access content of the directory, but can't write to it.  The bits here are in the ones column and the fours column, so the octal number that represents this permission is `5`.
- `+` indicates that there is "extended security information" associated with this directory which isn't shown in standard `ls` "long format".  An access control list, for example.

To set the basic permissions of this directory, you can use either the octal short-hand:

```
$ chmod 705 directoryname
```

or you can use the "symbolic" representation:

```
$ chmod u+rwx,g-rwx,o+rx-w directoryname
```

Obviously, the shorthand is ... shorter.

For the extended security information denoted by the `+`, you'd need to find out what is set up in order to replicate it.  The `ls` command has a `-e` option to have it show extended security settings.

To actually *set* your ACLs from the command line, you'd use chmod'a `=a`, `-a` and `+a` options.  Documentation about this is available in OSX from `man chmod`.  From that man page:

```
         Examples
          # ls -le
          -rw-r--r--+ 1 juser  wheel  0 Apr 28 14:06 file1
            owner: juser
            1: admin allow delete
          # chmod =a# 1 "admin allow write,chown"
          # ls -le
          -rw-r--r--+ 1 juser  wheel  0 Apr 28 14:06 file1
            owner: juser
            1: admin allow write,chown
```